# Next Auth custom redirect to subdomain issue

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm having issues in nextauth when redirecting back to a subdomain after a successful login. I've set up a custom
OAuthProvider [https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider](https://stackoverflow.com)
My app runs in different subdomains (each subdomain uses a different auth provider)

The issue i'm having is no matter what configuration I use, it redirects back to the url set in the .env for NEXTAUTH_URL. So when I log in from subdomain.example.com it redirects to example.com. I've tried everything in the config for adding a redirect_uri or callBackUrl. Even tried using the redirect callback.

I'm using the JWT strategy with no custom cookies defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Redirect Callback
async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
const { hostname } = new URL(url)
const { hostname: baseHostname } = new URL(baseUrl)

if (hostname !== baseHostname) {
Redirect to subdomain
const parts = hostname.split('.')
const subdomain = parts[0] // e.g. 'subdomain'
const domain = parts[1] // e.g. example.com
const newHostname = `${subdomain}.${domain}.com.au`
const newUrl = url.replace(hostname, newHostname)
return Promise.resolve(newUrl)
else {
return Promise.resolve(baseUrl)
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the same usecase but I think it might help:

I'm routing users to subdomains based on their oauth email using the `signIn()` callback:

```
    async signIn(user: any) {
      // get domain from user.email
      // redirect user to emailDomain.yourURL.com
      if (user?.user?.email) {
        const domain = user.user.email.split("@")[1].split(".")[0];
        const nextAuthURL = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || process.env.VERCEL_URL;
        // if the url includes slashes, do the below. if not add https:// to it
        const splitURL = nextAuthURL?.split("//");
        if (splitURL && splitURL.length > 1) {
          const urlWithSubdomain =
            splitURL[0] + "//" + domain + "." + splitURL[1];
          const subdomain = new URL(urlWithSubdomain);
          return subdomain.href;
        } else if (splitURL) {
          const urlWithSubdomain = "https://" + domain + "." + splitURL[0];
          const subdomain = new URL(urlWithSubdomain);
          return subdomain.href;
        }
        return true;
      }
      // fallback for credentials users who don't have a user email
      return true;
    }
```

Doesn't work in non-prod.